Loading Arc Diagram module in Highcharter R
I am trying to create an arc-diagram in Highcharter in R: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/highcharts/arc-diagram
I am running into the following error, however:

I know that I can use hc_add_dependency from the highcharter package to add in modules or plugins, however the documentation is not very descriptive, and I can't figure out how to load arc-diagram.js. I've tried each of the following variants:
hc_add_dependency(name = 'arc-diagram.js')
hc_add_dependency(name = 'modules/arc-diagram.js')
hc_add_dependency(name = 'plugins/arc-diagram.js')
But none of them work. They seem to be at least finding the module, according to this other error that I get:

I've also tried just loading in the module in a script() tag, but that doesn't work either.
Minimum Shiny reproducible example:
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)
library(htmlwidgets)


# Example data in long format
ex <- data.frame(
  source = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "E"),
  target = c("B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E", "F", "F"),
  value = c(10, 20, 15, 25, 10, 5, 20, 15)
)



ui <- fluidPage(
  # tags$head(
  #   # Attempt to load in the module via script tag
  #   tags$script(src = "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/arc-diagram.js")
  # ),

  # Highchart output
  highchartOutput("achart", width = "100%", height = "50%")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$achart <- renderHighchart({
    hchart(
      ex,
      "arcdiagram",
      hcaes(
        from = source,
        to = target,
        weight = value
      )
    ) %>%
      hc_chart(height = "80%") %>%
      # Attempt to add the dependency in
      hc_add_dependency(name = "modules/arc-diagram.js")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)





Unfortunately, the latest version of Highcharter available on CRAN uses Highcharts v9.3.1, while the arc diagram chart was implemented in Highcharts v10.0.0.
GH releases: https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/releases
HC changelog: https://www.highcharts.com/changelog/
As a workaround, you can install the development version from the Highcharter GitHub repository: https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter
And, once again, add the arc diagram module. The development version uses Highcharts v10.2.0, so it should work fine.
Here’s an example code for a simple arc diagram in R:
remotes::install_github("jbkunst/highcharter")

hchart <- highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = "arcdiagram") %>%
  hc_add_dependency("modules/arc-diagram.js") %>%
  hc_series(
    list(
      keys = c("from", "to", "weight"),
      type = "arcdiagram",
      linkWeight = 1.5,
      centeredLinks = TRUE,
      data = list(
        list(
          from = "Hamburg",
          to = "Stuttgart",
          weight = 1
        ),
        list(
          from = "Hamburg",
          to = "Frankfurt",
          weight = 1
        )
      )
    )
  )


print(hchart)


Installing from remote removes the module error - thank you for that. However I then get the following error trying to run your code: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tooltip')

I took a look at it, and it seems that the 'arcdiagram' object isn't created with default values for plotOptions, which causes the code to look for these values but not find them. The solution would be to extend the plotOptions with arcdiagram options before initializing the series by copying them from sankey.

Are you able to edit your example to demonstrate this?

Unfortunately, it does require a bit more work, and I don’t have the resources at the moment. However, I’ll try to revisit it when I have more time and will aim to prepare something. For now please keep your expectations in check.
